# Why is the checked attribute variable's value switching not updating the checkbox UI in LWC?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, lwc-wire-adapter

I have two input field of type checkbox in my record-edit-form

```
          <lightning-input-field
              variant="label-inline"
              field-name="President_Meeting_List__c"
              onchange={handleROValueChange}
              checked={isRoInputChecked}
            ></lightning-input-field>

            <lightning-input-field
              variant="label-inline"
              field-name="CRO__c"
              onchange={handleCROValueChange}
              checked={isCroInputChecked}
            ></lightning-input-field>
```

I need to switch the checked status of second one from onchange event of first field.

Js Controller

```
@Track isCroInputChecked;
@Track isRoInputChecked;

handleROValueChange(event) {
    this.roValue = event.target.value;
    this.isCroInputChecked=true;
 }
  
 handleCROValueChange(event) {
  this.croValue = event.target.value; 
  this.isRoInputChecked=true;
}
```

But it is not being checked in the UI. I can't even see the checked attribute for the checked checkbox through the inspect tool.
I need to update the changes ,i have seen many article suggested to do in this way to switch the state of checkbox ,But its not working for me.How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, JavaScript is case-sensitive. That means that `@Track` is not the same as `@track`. Always pay attention to case. Second, you do not need to `@track` single variables this way. The LWR (Lightning Web Runtime) checks these kinds of changes automatically. Third, `lightning-input-field` doesn't have a `checked` attribute. Use `value` to specify the value of the field.

```
   <lightning-input-field
      variant="label-inline"
      field-name="President_Meeting_List__c"
      onchange={handleROValueChange}
      value={isRoInputChecked}
    ></lightning-input-field>

    <lightning-input-field
      variant="label-inline"
      field-name="CRO__c"
      onchange={handleCROValueChange}
      value={isCroInputChecked}
    ></lightning-input-field>
```

Comment: .Thanks u saved my day bro..